# I am getting "unexpected ending of file" error in XML file of my current android project while using LinearLayout

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-12

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:text="123456"
        android:gravity="end|bottom"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me out

I have tried restarting the IDE but it isnt helping. I am not also getting autofill suggestion when i type in IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not formatted correctly since you do not have a closing tag for your outer **LinearLayout**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:text="123456"
        android:gravity="end|bottom"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout> /// <------------- This
```

Comment: @SohamDharap - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.